# Data is being inserted into DB even after the PHP script inserting data is stopped

Tags: php, postgresql

THis is something that I have been experiencing often. I am running a PHP script to insert data into a PostGreSql database. Now sometimes, if I stop this script execution in the middle, somehow the data still keeps getting added to the database.

Why is this happening and how do I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Note that just pressing "stop" in your browser doesn't actually stop the PHP script, it will just disconnect the browser from further output. The script will keep running on the server until it completes or times out.

Comment: @Mitch, that happens even when I "stop" the script in the beginning of execution and it inserts thousands of records.

Comment: @Piskvor I think you made the most sense of the problem! Can you tell me a way around it? Restarting the server may be??

Comment: Perhaps check for `!connection_aborted()` every now and then? See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: OK, I think this would work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that just pressing "stop" in your browser doesn't actually stop the PHP script (not on most servers anyway), it will just disconnect the browser from further output. The script will keep running on the server until it completes or times out.

Restarting the server will shut down any scripts running there, but that's like trying to kill a fly with a cannon.

In the simplest case, you may want to check for `!connection_aborted()` every now and then. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume your script is failing somehow? If so, you should use transactions. You start a transaction at the very beginning of your PHP script and commit it at the very end. If the script fails, the transaction will never be committed, and therefore will be rolled back. This way if your script fails your data will not be added to the db.

It will work more or less along these lines:

```
<?php
pg_query("BEGIN;");

// all of your PHP and pg code

// end of file    
pg_query("COMMIT;"); 
?>
```

You can also call manually pg_query("ROLLBACK;"); to cancel your transaction and rollback.

Besides, your script sholud never fail this way :)

Comment: It isnt a problem with the script failing. This happens when I want to stop the script executing due to some reason or the other.